# How to change the working directory of a Python script after is has been built into an EXE

Tags: python, operating-system

So I need to pack my program into an EXE with Pyinstaller and after I do that it cant find a text file that is in the same directory as the EXE itself is in. I have concluded that it is an issue with the directory being different from which it takes the files and it is for some reason it ends up in some folder in the local AppData

I have tried changing the working directory like so:

```py
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(script_dir)
```

but that didnt work and set the directory to something totally different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure on why this is giving you the AppData folder, but you should be able to get the path to the executable using this:

```
import os
import sys

exe_filepath = sys.argv[0]
exe_folder = os.path.basename(exe_filepath)
```

Comment: This helped in the general issue but for some scripts in the exe its still going for the appdata directory instead of the preset folder

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for
[importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html#importlib.resources.files).

The pyinstaller
[docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search)
describe how to use it:

> What To Bundle, Where To Search
>
> `--add-data` <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
>
> Additional non-binary files or folders to be added to the executable.

You may find it convenient to put details in a
[spec file](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files).

Your code can retrieve assets with
[pkgutil.get_data](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files):

> `help_bin = pkgutil.get_data('helpmod', 'help_data.txt')`

Pyinstaller supports
[several ways](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs)
of arranging for assets to be packaged and accessible
at run time.